# Add authentication in elasticsearch high level client for Java

Tags: java, authentication, elasticsearch

I am using an elasticsearch instance in elastic cloud instance secured with X-PACK.

I had been using the high level rest client before without any problems but I am unable to find how to send the basic authentication header on it.

I have tried to put the credentials as part of the URL but it didn't seem to be able to connect in that case.

Has anyone succeed to connect to a secured elasticsearch with high level rest client?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can specify the username and password to the Java Low Level REST Client and pass the Low Level REST Client to the `RestHighLevelClient` instance.

```
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"));

RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200))
        .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
            @Override
            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            }
        });

RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
```

**References:**

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-getting-started-initialization.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_basic_authentication.html

Comment: can you tell me how to do the same thing if I am using search-guard instead of X-Pack?

Answer (score 0):

Follow simple steps for making the RestHighLevelClient ready for connecting TLS+Auth Elastic Search

Create a CredentialsProvider using BasicCredentialsProvider provided by Apache httpclient like below

```
final CredentialsProvider credentialProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialProvider.setCredentials(
            AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
                    ES_USERNAME,
                    ES_PASSWORD
            ));
```

Create a HttpHost provide by apache using Host, Port and Protocol like below

```
HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost("ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOST", 9200, "https");
```

Here I used "https" since TLS is enabled on ES. You can use "http" for normal ES.

And the final step is to create RestHighLevelCLient like below

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(nodes)
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpAsyncClientBuilder -> {
                            httpAsyncClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialProvider);
                            return httpAsyncClientBuilder;
                        }
                ));
```