# Connect Elasticsearch using java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am new to `java` coming from `python`. I know there are lot of answers out there to connect `ElasticSearch` with `java`. But it is difficult for me to understand and some are outdated. In python, I can easily import `elasticsearch` module and connect to it.

Here's the Code in python:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch('localhost', port=9200, http_auth=('username', 'password'), scheme="http")
```

But in `java`, i have included the `elasticsearch` maven dependency in `pom.xml`. I want to connect to `elasticsearch`. I came to know `RestHighLevelClient` can do this job. I found this code. But don't know  how to make it connect to Elastic Search.

```
public RestHighLevelClient createESRestClient() {
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(esUserName, esPassword));

    RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient
            .builder(new HttpHost(esRestclientHost, 9200, "http"));
    // Use this one if your ElasticSearch server is setup to use username & password authentication
    if (esAuthentication) {
        restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(h -> h.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
    }

    return new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
}
```

Any one can help me or show me some sample code to connect with Elastic Search with java. In python, it was done in two lines. Help me with `java`.

Comment: Is your elasticsearch running up?? have you checked it in cmd??

Comment: @Vishwa Ratna, Yes, it was running fine in port 9200.

Comment: Informative: https://dzone.com/articles/elasticsearch-java-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For connecting elasticsearch using java you can use the below code:

```
public class ElasticsearchClient {
//private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticsearchClient.class);
private final RestHighLevelClient client;

public ElasticsearchClient(ElasticsearchConfig elasticsearchConfig) {
    client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(elasticsearchConfig.getHost(),
            elasticsearchConfig.getPort(), "http")));
}
}
```

**elasticsearchConfiguration:**

```
host: localhost

port: 9200
```

- For more information you can see [this](https://dzone.com/articles/elasticsearch-a-powerful-and-easy-search-engine-di-2) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html).

You can even follow instructions from this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.5/java-rest-high.html)

You need to add this dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>${es.client.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update 1**

Instead of separate config file, in order to add host and port inside code itself you can use below mentioned code:

```
public class ElasticsearchClient {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticsearchClient.class);
private final RestHighLevelClient client;


public ElasticsearchClient(ElasticsearchConfig elasticsearchConfig) {
    client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")));
}
```

Comment: @Paul Steven you can go through the updated part of my answer to know how to add host and port inside code itself, instead of separate config file :)

Comment: @Paul Steven are you now able to resolve your query??

Comment: Thanks.... it worked. I want to get data from elastic search index. Here code in python to get es index data:
`query = {'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'match_all': {}}], 'must_not': [], 'should': []}}, 'size': 10000}; 
results = es.search(index='index name', body=query);`   
Can u help me in java to get es index data.

Comment: Where to put the username and password for es in `httpHost`

Comment: @PaulSteven you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185570/add-authentication-in-elasticsearch-high-level-client-for-java?r=SearchResults to know how to add authentication for es

Answer (score 1):

For the current version Java REST Client version 7.5, follow the instructions at [ElasticSearch Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.5/java-rest-high.html):

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
        RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
```

[Maven repository](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.5/java-rest-high-getting-started-maven.html), ElasticSearch Client :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

All the API functions are specified at the client website: search, multi-search, index, etc.

The "Java Low Level REST Client" Basic Authentication is defined [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_basic_authentication.html):

```
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
    new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"));

RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200))
    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
        @Override
        public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(
                HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
            return httpClientBuilder
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
        }
    });
```

Comment: where to put the username and password of es in httphost?

Comment: @PaulSteven Answered at the answer. Source from elasticsearch website: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_basic_authentication.html